# Ungrouping dates values in a table in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have the following table - tbl1:

```
      ClientID  DateIn      DateOut  
      2293      04/06/2018  04/10/2018
      2295      08/05/2019  08/07/2019
```

I need the following result

```
       ClientID  Date
       2293      04/06/2018
       2293      04/07/2018
       2293      04/08/2018
       2293      04/09/2018
       2293      04/10/2018

       2295      08/05/2019
       2295      08/06/2019
       2295      08/07/2019
```

So, that instead of **DateIn** - **DateOut** , a new **[Date]** field will "expand" the above dates to a single values, associated with the **ClientID**.

I am a bit confused with the approach here. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use CTE recurcive

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ClientID ,DateIn ,DateOut  
    FROM T 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ClientID,
           DATEADD(DAY,1,DateIn),
           DateOut
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,DateIn) <= DateOut
)
SELECT ClientID,DateIn as 'Date'
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY ClientID,DateIn
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=26a242ce0e3633fadb7a452a4c17f6e9)

Comment: Worked perfectly!  I used to ask something like this before, but way more complex. I'll try to keep this one in mind for the future